# Reading from a stream

Tags: sml

I'm trying to read a word from a file that contains

```
   test
```

(Note the whitespace). The goal is to get the output "test". Here's what I've got so far:

```
val test = TextIO.openIn "test.txt"

fun stream_rdr stream = let fun get NONE = NONE
                  | get (SOME c) = SOME (c, stream)
            in get (TextIO.input1 stream)
            end 

fun skip s = StringCvt.skipWS stream_rdr s

fun read_word stream = let val s = skip stream
               in case StringCvt.splitl Char.isAlpha stream_rdr s
               of ("", rest_s) => NONE
                | (w, rest_s) => SOME (w, rest_s)
               end
```

The problem is that it doesn't quite work.

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Sun Jun 29 03:29:51 2014]
- use "Read.ml" ;;
[opening Read.ml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val test = - : TextIO.instream
val stream_rdr = fn
  : TextIO.instream -> (TextIO.elem * TextIO.instream) option
val skip = fn : TextIO.instream -> TextIO.instream
val read_word = fn : TextIO.instream -> (string * TextIO.instream) option
val it = () : unit
- read_word test ;;
val it = SOME ("est",-) : (string * TextIO.instream) option
-
```

I'm assuming that's to do with how I defined `stream_rdr`, but I can't see a good way of defining it so that it both makes progress, AND avoids dropping rejected chars to `skipWS` or `splitl`. General comments welcome, but specifically...

1. Is there a pre-defined `(char, instream) reader` with this behavior somewhere?
2. Regardless of whether it exists or not, how would I write one (if it does exist, I'd appreciate being pointed to its source code)?
3. Is there an entirely different approach that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is, that your reader (subtly) violates the semantics for readers.

In this case, `StringCvt.skipWS` assumes, that if it calls `stream_rdr s`, and gets a `SOME (c, s')` back, then the original `s` remains unmodified.

That is, it can try to read a character from the character source until it runs into a non-whitespace character, and then simply return the first one that doesn't return a whitespace character. This is a problem in your case, however, since calling `stream_rdr` modifies `s`.

In order to resolve this problem, I'd recommend making use of the character reader provided by the [`scanStream`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/text-io.html#SIG:TEXT_IO.scanStream:VAL) function from `TextIO`, rather than constructing your own character reader (`stream_rdr`).

Comment: In particular, the default scanner for `Bool` ended up being instructive. If you have `mlton` installed from the Debian repos, you can find the sources in `/usr/lib/mlton/sml/basis/general/bool.sml`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking Sebastian's advice and writing this:

```
val test = TextIO.openIn "test.txt"

fun scan_word reader state = let
    val s = StringCvt.skipWS reader state
in case StringCvt.splitl Char.isAlpha reader s of
       ("", ns) => NONE
     | (w, ns) => SOME (w, ns)
end

fun scan stream = TextIO.scanStream scan_word stream
```

It does what I want with the same input as before:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Sun Jun 29 03:29:51 2014]
- [read.sml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val test = - : TextIO.instream
val scan_word = fn : (char,'a) StringCvt.reader -> 'a -> (string * 'a) option
val scan = fn : TextIO.instream -> string option
val it = () : unit
- scan test ;;
val it = SOME "test" : string option
-
```

The solution is based on a reading of the built-in [`Bool.scan`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/bool.html#SIG:BOOL.scan:VAL:SPEC). If you've got `mlton` installed from the Debian repos, you'll find the source at `/usr/lib/mlton/sml/basis/general/bool.sml`. The relevant part is included below:

```
 ...
  fun scan reader state =
     case reader state of
        NONE => NONE
      | SOME(c, state) =>
           case c of
              #"f" => (case Reader.reader4 reader state of
                          SOME((#"a", #"l", #"s", #"e"), state) =>
                             SOME(false, state)
                        | _ => NONE)
            | #"t" => (case Reader.reader3 reader state of
                          SOME((#"r", #"u", #"e"), state) =>
                             SOME(true, state)
                        | _ => NONE)
            | _ => NONE
 ...
```